# Как исправить данную проблему?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

В коде есть дата, но при запросе выводит эта ошибка:
Error Number: 1064
The Error returned was:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '07:58:25 WHERE `user_id` = 12' at line 1

```
$date_table = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
$db->query( "UPDATE `dle_users` SET date_table = {$date_table} WHERE `user_id` = ".$member_id['user_id']."" );
```

Как исправить данную проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дату необходимо экранировать, это не числовое значение.

```
$db->query( "UPDATE `dle_users` SET date_table = '{$date_table}' WHERE `user_id` = ".$member_id['user_id']."" );
```

Comment: Спасибо! Заработало!